# Removing element from nested array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an upvoting/downvoting application using MongoDB and Node.JS
I have created two interlinked schemas:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Voters = require('./voters');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  voters: [Voters.schema],
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});


mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

and for voters:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var votersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    voter_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    votetype: Number

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Voters', votersSchema);
```

For including users in the voters array, I'm using this code:

```
    var voterModel = new Voters();
    voterModel.voter_id = req.payload._id;
    voterModel.votetype = 1;
    foundPost.voters.push(voterModel);
    foundPost.save();
```

Which works just fine. For removing users I tried several methods, but none seem to work. The current one is $pull:

```
    foundPost.update({'voters.voter_id': req.payload._id}, {$pull: {'voters': {'voter_id': req.payload._id, 'votetype': 1}}}, function(err){
      if (err) { console.log(err); }
    });
```

The update action works in the mongo shell, but not from within node. I also tried foundPost.voters.remove, but the result was the same. Also tried Voters.findOne, but the query always returns null.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `id` method first to find the *voter* then remove it and last save document to apply changes:

```
var voter = foundPost.voters.id(req.payload._id).remove();
foundPost.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('the voter was removed')
});
```

Comment: The train of thougth was right, thank you! I also had to change the voter_id variable in the voter model, but it works now.

Comment: Sure, also consider a quick skim on subdocuments CRUD operations:  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html